# Android Gradle Implementation vs CompileOnly Performance

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations) mention that `implementation` provides significant build time improvements over `compile`/`api`. What about `compileOnly`?

My use case is a multi-module (sorry I don't like Gradle's multi-project terminology) project, where I have an Android app, and multiple libraries that the app depends on (`implementation`). Some of the libraries also depend on one another. Should I use `implementation` or `compileOnly` when declaring dependencies in the library modules? My app module will be using `implementation` to depend on those artifacts, so I don't need them to be transitive through the library modules.

Comment: `compileOnly` means that those dependencies would be accessible though compile time only, and **not** accessible during runtime. If you module does not need those dependencies on runtime I see no issues declaring them `compileOnly`.

Comment: That doesn't address the question, which is regarding performance.

Answer (score 36):

The `api` configuration should be used for dependencies that are exported to external `modules` **(transitive dependency)**. Vice-Versa `implementation` configuration should be used for dependencies that are internal to the component **(not transitive dependency)**.

**implementation vs [compileOnly](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies)**:

There is no similarity in their job, `compileOnly` is

- a configuration inherited from java-plugin
- required at compile time
- also not included in the runtime classpath or exposed to dependent
  projects.

So `compileOnly` doesn't replace the `implementation` configuration job e.g:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0' // can't use compileOnly here
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8" // can't use here also
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8" // can't use here also
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0' // we can use compileOnly here because it's required on run time only.
```

Since your case is a "multi-module", you have to use the `api` configuration, until you reach the final module it's better to use `implementation`.

Following graph describe those configurations:

[image]

**Performance?**

I think `api` requires more memory because *gradle* will snapshot every class in that **transitive** *module*, vice versa `implementation` is a preferred configuration because (as mentioned above) it's used for its own internal implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but my question is what improvements, if any, are there to using `compileOnly` over `implementation`.

Comment: Still not quite there. The gradle doc for `compileOnly` says "Dependencies whose API is required at compile time but whose `implementation` is to be provided by a consuming library, application or runtime environment." My question is, is there any benefit to declaring my library's dependencies as `compileOnly` vs `implementation` since both would work (with the caveat being that the consuming module would need to declare those dependencies as `implementation` iif they're in the public API).

Comment: @Eliezer as @azizbekian suggest in comments, if you don't need module in run-time yes use `compileOnly` this well reduce memory usage.

Comment: More so then implementation, or on the same level?

Comment: @Eliezer sry, i didn't under stand that, what you mean?

Comment: Is using `compileOnly` going to give better performance than using `implementation`, the same performance as `implementation`, or worse performance than `implementation`?

Comment: `Is using compileOnly going to give better performance than using implementation` sure.

Comment: @Ibrahim `compileOnly` & `implementation` r two very different  dependency declarations. You use `compileOnly` in a library module to allow a client app to “optionally” implement/use the dependency. If they want to use it, then they’ll have to declare it on their own in their app module. If they don’t declare the dependency, then it’s not added to the classpath, thus making a smaller APK with less dependencies. And sure, it’ll give performance benefits... but that’s not what it’s use case is for. If you just start switching `implementation` for `classPath` you’ll run into trouble quickly.

Comment: the last comment in the code should be compile time only ?