# Configuration 'compile' in is deprecated, but all configurations are 'implementation'

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I receive following warning while executing gradle in android:

```
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated.
```

But all my dependencies included via implementation configuration. (And modules too)
Are there any "invisible" dependencies in gradle?

Here is my main build gradle file: https://pastebin.com/ZJe7zrwn

Comment: i am getting same error. did you get any solution?

Comment: Came here looking for the answer and then actually found It turned out to be a simple find and replace.

Answer (score 14):

I found this working solution while compiling my code today. (When everything is `implementation` and nothing is `compile` in your `build.gradle`)

**Errors:**

```
 1. Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated 
 2. registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders (FileCollection)
```

**Solution:**

I needed to update my **Project: build.gradle**

from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any "invisible" dependencies in gradle?

I don't know whether it's responsible for this problem, but plugins can add dependencies, and in particular `com.google.gms.google-services` [does](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin):

> The google-services plugin has two main functions: ...
>
> 2. Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled.

Comment: Is there any way to confirm that this plugin is generating the warning ?

Answer (score 4):

replace in path  ctrl+shift+R

Select project
[image: find replace snip]

type in "provided" replace with "compileOnly" or replace "compile" with "implementation"
make sure your only changing the gradle.build files 
If you have some angst then just open the gradle.build files and edit them.

[image: gradle snip]

Comment: Thanks, indeed what I needed to do was to remove the 'compile' statements and leave only the 'implementation' ones as both compile/testCompile are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I think you received warning because you use,

```
compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28"
```

a better explanation is given here,

[Android Gradle Implementation vs CompileOnly Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556474/android-gradle-implementation-vs-compileonly-performance)

Comment: compileOnly is not deprecated

Comment: replaced compileOnly with implementation and still receive this warning