# annotationProcessor gradle 4.7+ configuration doesn't run lombok

Tags: gradle, lombok

I have received the following message when working with a gradle 4.7 project

```
The following annotation processors were detected on the compile classpath: 'lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor' and 'lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$ClaimingProcessor'. Detecting annotation processors on the compile classpath is
Deprecated and Gradle 5.0 will ignore them. Please add them to the annotation processor path instead. If you did not intend to use annotation processors, you can use the '-proc:none' compiler argument to ignore them.
```

when running

```
gradlew build --warning-mode=all
```

on a project with the following Gradle configuration

```
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testCompileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
```

As the warning suggests, it is recommended to place these on the `annotationProcessor` (and `testAnnotationProcessor`) configurations in order to be compatible with gradle 5.0

```
annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testAnnotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
```

However, with a simple test:

```
@Slf4j
public class LombokTests {
    @Test
    public void lombokCompiles() {
        log.info("foobar");
    }
}
```

That configuration fails:

```
> Task :compileTestJava FAILED
D:\Users\bobjones\repos\my-new-app\src\test\java\com\example\app\LombokTests.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
@Slf4j
 ^
  symbol: class Slf4j
1 error
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Add the `compileOnly`/`testCompileOnly` configuration

```
annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testAnnotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testCompileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
```

---

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7-rc-1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_compile_avoidance), the annotationProcessor config still requires the `compileOnly` (and `testCompileOnly` for test classes) configuration to function. As for support for incremental annotation processing, the implementers of Lombok have just merged in support to master but as of 25th May 2018 have not included a go-live version.

Their last version 16.2.20 spanning commits up until the [9th of Jan 2018](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/commits/v1.16.20) and the Gradle change was pulled into master on the [15th of May 2018](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/commit/366d18c8614d00e17447781796c65ee693251d5c) So I suspect the new version won't be far from release, although their ['Edgy'](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge) release does not include any notes regarding this feature.

### EDIT October 2020:

A [Gradle plugin is available by io.freefair](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok) that configures these settings and more automatically and helps keep lombok up-to-date (of course you may override the lombok version yourself).

Comment: I think it should be `compileOnly` and `testCompileOnly` for lombok as annotations shouldn't be available at runtime. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786388/48136) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Brice, I'll give it a try and read that answer then edit my response if appropriate :D

Comment: I forgot to say that otherwise `implementation` / `compile` will export lombok as a transitive dependency or during the runtime, which is wrong as lombok should only be available on the compile classpath, not the runtime classpath or to lib consumers.

Comment: @coderatchet thank you very much for your answer. It helped a lot