# Jackson deserialization of subtype fails when run with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jackson

I am getting an exception when running an integration test with gradle.

The exception I'm getting is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of AbstractCommonDetails: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

The Summary class has the following annotations on the details I am trying to deserialize:

```
@Data
public class Summary {
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, include = PROPERTY, property = "@type")
  @JsonSubTypes({
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CardDetails.class, name = "CARD")
  })
  private AbstractCommonDetails details;
}
```

AbstractCommonDetails looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractCommonDetails {
  private Long id;
  public abstract String getPaymentMethod();
}
```

And the CardDetails has `@JsonTypeName("CARD")` and `@Data` annotations and the implementation of `getPaymentMethod` method.

ObjectMapper configuration and deserializing is done as follows:

```
new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules().readValue(IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8"), Summary.class);
```

And sample json:

```
{
  "details":{
    "@type":"CARD",
    "amount":"10.00"
}
```

Weird thing is - running the integration test as a Junit test succeeds but when running the same integration test with `gradlew test` command it fails with the exception mentioned before. What could be the cause?

Comment: Could you show us how `AbstractCommonDetails` class looks like? How do you run `Junit` test? In `IDE` or `Maven`?

Comment: Junit test is run in IDE. Posted the code of AbstractCommonDetails

Comment: if it does not work with `gradle` it means we need to configure somehow `Lambok` annotations to work. Could you check for example that [annotationProcessor gradle 4.7+ configuration doesn't run lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519138/annotationprocessor-gradle-4-7-configuration-doesnt-run-lombok)

Comment: I'll try removing lombok annotations and running the tests to verify if that is where the problem lies.

Comment: @MichałZiober removing lombok annotations indeed fixed the problem - I'll try getting it to work using the example with lombok. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If test works on `IDE` but does not work with `gradle` it means you need to take a look on `gradle` configuration. You use `Lambook`, so you need to be sure that `gradle` configuration is aware about `Lambok` annotations.

See also:

- [annotationProcessor gradle 4.7+ configuration doesn't run lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519138/annotationprocessor-gradle-4-7-configuration-doesnt-run-lombok)
- [Documentation](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle)